# InvokeAction yields App Crash

Tags: windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

using V2.0.0.5 - beta (not via nuget but compiled source).

All through out the application I am using Multi-View over single ViewModel. On one particular view now after a conversion from SQLCE to SQLite, I am getting either a race condition or invalid contextual return when it builds up the on the InvokeAction. One thing I am noticing is a ArgumentException on System.Windows.ni.dll and well the part of the problem is the Telerik Control primitives.dll... RadTransitionControl

The only difference between this view and another with almost exactly the same build out is the way I populate the view.  The view is using a "non-table" viewmodel that I built up to show some related information between 2 related tables.  When I selected one of the elements in the boundlist it presents RadMenu (edit/delete) selecting edit works goes into the method expected, using the data passed in from the selection event I am able to re-hydrate the dataitem in question to respective objects. And populate the view but it dies before completing the transition from view to view.

The thing that blows my mind here is that I am using that control all over for Transistions from one view piece to another, if I change the control to ContentControl it works just fine. Other views that have that control work as expected.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving some of the code around and separating some of the bundled code resulted in this not occurring guess problem fixed...